# How do you set up a VFD to run a motor at 2 different speeds?

Tags: plc, vfd, automation, fluid-pump

I'm already familiar with the concept of altering the frequency to change the speed of the motor. So in this scenario, I'm looking into running a pump at 40Hz (high speed) and 23Hz (low speed). This is so that the oil pumped doesn't overflow or exceed the requirements.

On the drive itself there are analogue input and analogue output terminals. Where would I connect if I want the motor to run at 2 different speeds and why?

Any sort of help would be appreciated

Link to drive manual: 
http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.invt.com/uploadfiles/2017/10/pc_self_service_2017102511020828.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjqnLbrkbPfAhVRzhoKHUwFC7QQFggRMAI&usg=AOvVaw2Q69nCaCrAiIFEycntYFjl

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link for the user manual of your VFD. They are not all the same.

Comment: I just added the link to the VFD manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 170 of the [Goodrive 200 user manual](http://www.invt.com/uploadfiles/2017/10/pc_self_service_2017102511020828.pdf) says

> The 16 step speeds can be set by the combination of
> digital state of four terminals.
> Note: multi-step speed 1 is the low position, multi-step
> speed 4 is the high position.

This means that you can select up to 16 preset speeds by binary pattern.

```
3  2  1  0  |  Speed
------------+-------
0  0  0  0  |  0
0  0  0  1  |  1
0  0  1  0  |  2
0  0  1  1  |  3
...
1  1  1  1    15
```

It appears that the speeds are set in "P10 Group Simple PLC and multi-step speed control" on page 115.

---

[image]

Alternatively connect multiple pots to two (or up to three) analog inputs and figure out how to switch between one pot setting and the other.